# Adding CSS to embedded Tableau data on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, tableau-api

I am trying to add custom CSS to  a Tableau data Visualization embedded from Tableau public onto my WordPress site  (built with SiteOrigin theme).

I am not trying to style to container it’s in by rather elements within the iframe itself (moving a toolbar closer to the graph). I can do it successfully with chrome dev tools, but when using that elements ID and adding the additional CSS to Wordpress it does not work. Any suggestions on how to target this iframe element? Is it even possible on the Wordpress site itself?

I tried using the elements ID to add the CSS in Wordpress in the additional CSS section. I am not able to successfully target the ID.

Comment: Styling does not "inherit" into iframes. You would need to _inject_ your styling directly into the document loaded into the iframe - but that will only be possible, if the iframe content is loaded from the same origin, and from your description it sounds like that was not the case.